# Установка программы на Ubuntu. Проблема с CMake

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, sfml

Я пытаюсь установить программу тестирования (https://github.com/o-reo/push_swap_visualizer) на мой Microsoft Visual Code, работающий на wsl-ubuntu. Разработчик программы говорит, что для установки мне нужно клонировать программу с гитхаба, а затем запустить команду "cmake..." Также для этой программы-тестера требуются C++17, cmake, SFML и ImGui. Когда я запускаю "cmake...", я получаю такое сообщение об ошибке:

```
-- Found ImGui v1.82 in /home/aputiev/projects/03/push_swap_test/push_swap_visualizer/build/_deps/imgui-src
-- Fetching SFML...
-- libudev stable: 0
-- Found UDev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so
--    include: /usr/include
CMake Error at build/_deps/sfml-src/cmake/Macros.cmake:296 (message):
  Missing item in FREETYPE_LIBRARY
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  build/_deps/sfml-src/src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeLists.txt:137 (sfml_find_package)
```

P.S. я установил cmake и SFML, библиотеку libssl-dev с «sudo apt install libssl-dev». Я совершенно новичок в программировании. Не могли бы вы помочь мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: Гугл по тексту ошибки. В первом же результате рекомендуют установить `libfreetype-dev`

Comment: Спасибо Вам, помогло! Я гуглил, но почему-то натыкался на libfreetype6-dev, а не libfreetype-dev. И libfreetype6-dev не помгал...

Comment: Правда теперь при попытке запуска программы выдается другая ошибка: Failed to open X11 display; make sure the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly

Comment: Ну правильно, раз это визуализатор, то нужен X сервер для отрисовки графики. Погуглите как установить X сервер в Windows для WSL. У меня WSL-1, было несложно настроить Xming. Если же у вас вторая версия, то там нужно какие-то шаманские танцы танцевать, насколько помню.